# Component instantiation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I need some help with component instantiations (port maps) in VHDL. I have a 16 bit Full Adder which I want to import in my ALU, and it should trigger when the `opcode` turns "000". In the following code I have, `Sum` and `Carry` are going undefined after using the testbench. I took help from [here](http://www.altera.com/support/examples/vhdl/v_hier.html) to implement the port map. Maybe I'm not using the test bench correctly here.

**FullAdder16Bit.vhd**:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity FullAdder16Bit is
    port(A,B: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Cin: in std_logic;
        Sum: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Cout: out std_logic);
end FullAdder16Bit;

architecture behavior of FullAdder16Bit is

begin
    process(A,B,Cin)
    variable carry: std_logic;

    begin
    carry:=Cin;
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
        carry:=(A(i) and B(i)) or (carry and (A(i) or B(i)));
        end loop;
    sum<=A + B + Cin;
    Cout<=carry;
    end process;
end behavior;
```

**ALU16Bit.vhd**:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
entity arith is
port(A,B: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    opcode: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    Sum: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    Carry: out std_logic;
    mult: buffer std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end arith;
architecture rtl of arith is
component FullAdder16Bit is
    port(A,B: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Cin: in std_logic;
        Sum: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Cout: out std_logic);
end component;
signal areg,breg,sreg:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal cinreg,coutreg:std_logic;
begin
Add: FullAdder16Bit port map(A=>A,B=>B,Cin=>'0',Sum=>Sum,Cout=>Carry);
process(A,B,opcode)
begin
Sum<=(others=>'0');
Carry<='0';
mult<=(others=>'0');
case opcode is
when "000" =>
areg<=A; breg<=b;cinreg<='0'; Sum<=sreg; Carry<=coutreg;
when others =>
Sum<=(others=>'Z');
Carry<='Z';
mult<=(others=>'Z');
end case;
end process;
end rtl;
```

**tb_ALU16Bit.vhd**:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity tb_arith is
end tb_arith;
architecture structure of tb_arith is
component arith is
port(A,B: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    opcode: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    Sum: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    Carry: out std_logic;
    mult: buffer std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end component;
signal A,B,Sum: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal Carry: std_logic;
signal opcode: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal mult: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
DUT: arith port map(A,B,opcode,Sum,Carry,mult);
process
begin
wait for 0 ns;
opcode<="000";
A<="0000111111111111";
B<="1111111111111111";
wait for 10 ns;
opcode<="001";
A<="0000111111111111";
B<="1111111111111111";
wait;
end process;
end structure;
configuration tb_arith_con of tb_arith is
for structure
end for;
end tb_arith_con;
```

Comment: You have multiple drivers on Sum,Cout. Both the Adder and the process drive these signals and that is probably your problem. The process does nothing useful anyway.

Comment: Ayush = As Brian writes you have multiple drivers. This is another case where adding another wait statement in your test bench would have pointed to the problem. If you were to add say `wait for 10 ns;` before the `wait;` in the unlabeled process in `tb_arith`, you'd see that your results show up when `opcode` is "001" an one set of drivers outputs all 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a look at the testbench so no comments on functionality but your port map is wrong. Essentially what you're doing with a port map is connecting signals to various ports, the signals can have any name you like but like many coders you have named your signals the same as your ports which makes a lot of sense although is not always practical. I think your instantiation should read something like this:

```
DUT: arith
port map ( 
                A       =>  A,
                B       =>  B,
                opcode  =>  opcode,
                Sum     =>  Sum,
                Carry   =>  Carry,
                mult    =>  mult

            );
```

Which is basically saying connect port A to signal A, port B to signal B connect port opcode to signal opcode and so on.

If you are just starting out, consider getting a good textbook with examples, I would recommend VHDL: Programming by Example, I don't agree with all the examples given as being optimum but it is a really good reference book, I haven't found a better one.

Hope this helps,

Gipsy